# How do you say "para" (paraprofessional) in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word, word-requests

I am trying to figure out a translation for paraprofessional in Chinese, Google translate gave me "辅助专业人员”. While the NYC Public School website gave something like “助教” or “专业辅助”.  However, I am pretty sure “助教” means assistant teacher. Furthermore, the website is also Google Translated.

For para, I mean those who assist students with special needs by accompanying them through their classes.

I am wondering if there is a official translation for "paraprofessionals". Both in its full name, and it its abbreviation(缩写) “para".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chinese term is almost certainly something like 教輔人員, while this is literally teacher assistant, its not the same as english "assistant teacher".  This covers all teaching assistant roles, whether its someone helping write class schedules, do paperwork, help individual students with special needs, english assistant teachers, or many others.  The term is just any person helping the actual teacher teaching in some way, if that makes sense.

So paraprofessional as you describe it would also fit-- in chinese this position is probably not actually recognized as a teacher themselves, although that certainly doesn't mean the position isn't appreciated, for clarity.

I recommend you can add a brief description of what type of work you do as a paraprofessional, and that can easily let people know what type of assistant to the teacher you are-- for example 教輔人員 with 特殊教育 will clearly be helping students that need extra assistance, together with 务行政工作 people will know you help on the administrative side of organizing the class process, etcetcetc (◐‿◑)﻿

Comment: I see, so my understanding is that 教辅人员 would be a staff that has a similar role as a assistant teacher.

Comment: @Monokuma yes, basically it covers everything in the english assistant teacher, plus more things not described that way in english, like administrator or scheduler or aide or invigilator or researcher or even a teacher that has stepped back to just assisting newer teachers.  Even student counselors are considered in the same category as 教辅人员,  although usually described by a different term. You get the idea, its a very inculsive term, so you can further specify the details, just like a teacher themselves would add on to specify what they teach （＾ν＾）

Answer (score 2):

Paraprofessional is a title given to individuals in various occupational fields, such as **education**, **librarianship**, **healthcare**, **engineering, and law**. Historically, paraprofessionals assisted the master professional of their field.

The Greek prefix "para-" indicates beside or side by side (as in "parallel"); hence, a paraprofessional is one who works alongside a professional, while being a professional themselves.

In the field of education, a paraprofessional is known as a **paraeducator (辅助教育者)** - instructional assistant or educational assistant, such as "**teacher's aide (教学助理)**" or "**classroom assistant (课堂助理)**", is a teaching-related position within a school generally responsible for specialized or concentrated assistance for students in elementary and secondary schools.

I think “助教 (teaching assistance - in college)” and "家庭教师/功課輔導 (tutor - in general)" can also be classified as a "paraeducator".

Comment: Also very detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

(因智力或身体残疾所需要的)特殊护理
(because of mental or physical disability in need of) special care

特殊护理的人员: special needs carer

Comment: I see, so something like a carer or nurse would also fit into a para.

Comment: Well, the idea in para is also in parallel from para allēlois "beside one another,": The idea in  paramedic is "not fully qualified: doing the same but cheaper" as I understand it. In America I believe they use the term 'first responder', who is not a medical doctor, maybe a nurse, or just someone well trained in first aid and therefore cheaper. Maybe I have not grasped the concept correctly, but then, why qualify if the paramedic is a medic??

Comment: I see, so based on this, you can say that a "para" in the education field is the first responder to the student(s)' needs. While also fitting the criteria for someone who is side by side.  While in the medical field it is very clear, as those who are trained in first aid (EMT) are considered paramedics as well.